# Updating 'sum line lengths' polygon layer when line layer is updated

Tags: qgis

After using sum line lengths, is there an automated way to update the resulting polygon layer when more lines are added without needing to delete the layer and re-run the sum line lengths algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You should try a **"dynamic query"**.
Depending on how your data are stored u can try either a **virtual layer** (based on this dynamic query) or a postgis "view" (which is something "dynamic" and re-run each time a change occurs in the underlying tables ...)

Make a quick search about it in here ...

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what I'm finding under the dynamic query search.  I currently have a layer of lines, and a layer of polygons, When I run sum line lengths I get the results I desire, showing lengths and counts of lines per each polygon. I cant however figure out how to get that data without running that algorithm though.

Comment: The sum line lengths tool creates a new layer every time you run it. I don't think you can incorporate it into a dynamic query. However, it should be possible to add virtual fields to the polygon layer that display length and count of lines that intersect each polygon.

Comment: Hmm, this is more challenging than I first thought. I added a length field to the line layer, and used intersecting_geom_sum() to calculate the total length of all lines that intersect the polygon, but it seems the Sum Line Lengths tool calculates the total length of lines *cropped to fit within the polygon.*

Answer (score 0):

Following [snaileater](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21733/snaileater)'s answer, this is a `Virtual Layer` syntax to mimic `Sum line lengths` assuming:

- the polygon layer name is `Polygon` and it has unique `id` field
- the line layer name is `Line`

please modify `Polygon` and `Line` to your actual layer names.

```
SELECT 
       Polygon.id AS id, 
       Round(Sum(st_length(st_intersection(Line.geometry, Polygon.geometry))), 5) AS LENGTH, 
       Count(st_intersection(Line.geometry, Polygon.geometry)) AS COUNT,
       Polygon.geometry AS geometry
FROM Line INNER JOIN polygon
ON st_intersects(Line.geometry, Polygon.geometry) 
GROUP BY Polygon.id
ORDER BY Polygon.id
```

However, I would recommend to stick to `Sum line lengths` tool, if you have already started building your database with this tool. You will never be satisfied with their consistency (including accuracy and repeatability), if you mix tools for length/area measurements.

---

**EDIT**

This is how it looks when your layer name / field name fit into. Also please avoid name starting with numbers (e.g, `161kv`).

```
SELECT 
       County.Cnty_NM AS id, 
       Round(Sum(st_length(st_intersection(161kv.geometry, County.geometry))), 5) AS LENGTH, 
       Count(st_intersection(161kv.geometry, County.geometry)) AS COUNT,
       County.geometry AS geometry
FROM 161kv INNER JOIN County
ON st_intersects(161kv.geometry, County.geometry) 
GROUP BY County.Cnty_NM
ORDER BY County.Cnty_NM
```

Comment: I'll try the method pointed out here, I do like the sum line lengths for its simplicity but when my line layers change it appears the only way to update that results are deleting and re-running that tool which could be cumbersome down the road.

Comment: I apparently cant seem to get the above syntax to work. My polygon layer is named "County" unique ID field is "Cnty_NM" my line layer is "161kv". I replaced the instances of polygon, ID and Line with my information but it does not seem to yield any results like sum line lengths does.

Comment: @JoshuaLind See an example in the edit.

Comment: Kazuhito, Thank you for the edited example.  I've updated my layers to not start with numbers per recommendations but my virtual layer returns 0 features.  Does that information in your example not go into the query field when trying to add a virtual layer?

Comment: @JoshuaLind Have you imported your layers to start creating virtual layer?

Comment: Yeah, both layers were added to the section above the query field by clicking on import and selecting the desired layers.

Comment: @JoshuaLind OK. Then I have no idea what causes the failure. Sorry.

Comment: Kazuhito, I discovered what my issue was after starting a new project. The CRS between my line layer and county layer did not match. After correcting the issue the virtual layer works exactly as expected.